# How to replace a url having brackets with hyperlink/anchor tag in the text C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am trying to replace all occurrences of URLs with an anchor tag.
I am able to do this for most of the URL characters but the code is breaking when there is a `(` and `)` in the URL.

For ex.

> `https://example.com/Heavy-Industry/Global-Perfluorosulfonic-Acid-(PFSA)-Market-Status-By-Manufacturers,-Types-And-Application,-History-And-Forecast-2025#sample`

Here is my code:

```
protected string MakeLink(string text)
{
    string text2 = Regex.Replace(text,
        @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
        "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");

    return text2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the parenthesis to the character class `[\w\-.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#()]`

If you are not using the capturing groups, I think you could make your regex a bit more compact by using a single capturing group for the replacement.

Note that you don't have to escape the dot and the plus sign inside the character class.

`((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\w\-_]+(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+(?:[\w\-.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#()]*[\w\-@?^=%&amp;/~+#])?)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dawtgE/1) | [Demo C#](http://rextester.com/IMY62054)